# How to count the number of children for each mother

Tags: stata

I have the following structure

[image]

In the image I want to have a variable which count the number of children for each person in a household. For example in the household 0001000 the person(ls) number 1 have 0 children, the person number 2 have 3 children and so on

Comment: can you show what you have done already? where you are stuck? Or are you hoping someone here will do your homework for you?

Comment: I just could do the variable mmnino which counts the number of children of each mother. In this case I have 3 children for mother 2 but i can't put the 3 in the row of mother 2 and zeros in the other members. Sorry I'm just initializing with stata.

Comment: If Stata could read pictures of data so I could test my recommendation, I would have given an answer. Sorry. Here's a hint: I think I would use `collapse` to count children by folio and id_mother, `rename`, and `merge`, for starters.

Comment: I used "by folio id_mother, gen mmnino = _N if id_mother != ." to count children by folio and by id_mother. I have no idea why to use merge here

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that `id_mother` is the same (if not missing) within `folio`, how about something like the following?

```
egen famid = group(folio)
sort famid
by famid: egen mmm = mean(id_mother)
by famid: egen kkk = count(id_mother)
gen mmnino = kkk if famid*100+ls==famid*100+mmm
drop famid kkk mmm
list
```

Above, the first line is not required if `folio` is numeric. Should try with actual data to debug. Instead of Line 4 (for `egen kkk`), you can also do something like:

```
by famid: egen sss = sum(id_mother)
gen kkk = sss/mmm
```